# Populating/Binding an outlet with list items dynamically from a model array?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to an array elements and populate an outlet with list format. I would like to know what would be the best practice, please. I have a very simple App, I have declared a color array within "ColorModel". I would like to populate/bind the outlet labeled "homeContent" within "home" (data-template-name) with all the colors from this array dynamically. I am uncertain where and how to dynamically bind content, should the content be bound to "App.ColorController"? I have done online searches and got some fiddles, but those approaches weren't straight forward. I appreciate all your help. Thanks.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exciter/sqJEh/

App Code:

```
$(function(){

    App = Ember.Application.create({
        ready: function(){
            alert("APP INIT");
        }
    });

    //APP 
    App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: "application",
        classNames: ['']
    });

    //NAVBAR
    App.HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.HomeView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: "home",
        classNames: ['']
    });

    //MODELS

    //COLORS
    App.ColorModel = Ember.Object.create({
        //COLOR ARRAY
        var colorArr: Ember.A(["Orange","Blue","Green","Yellow","White","Grey","Purple","Silver","Black","Maroon","Sunburst"]);
    });

    App.ColorController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.ColorView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: '',
        classNames: ''
    }); 


    App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
        enableLogging: true,
        location: 'hash',

        root: Ember.Route.extend({
            //EVENTS
            gotoHome: Ember.Route.transitionTo('home');

            home: Ember.Route.extend({
                router: '/',
                connectOutlets: function(router, context){
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
                }
            }),
        })
    });
    App.initialize();
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
    {{outlet homeContent}}
</script>
```

Here are the questions:

In your fiddle, you have color Array:

```
var colors = ["Orange","Blue","Green",
               "Yellow","White","Grey",
               "Purple","Silver","Black",
               "Maroon","Sunburst"]
```

I have been declaring arrays this way:

```
var color: Ember.A(["Orange","Blue","Green",
               "Yellow","White","Grey",
               "Purple","Silver","Black",
               "Maroon","Sunburst"])
```

**Question 1:**
Which is the best practice Ember preaches?

In your fiddles' HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
   {{#each color in controller}}
     {{color}}           
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

I understand where the "colors" are coming from, but where you have {{#each color in controller}},

**Question 2:**
Where is that "color" coming from? 
Is it a for-in loop?

**Question 3:**
As I to understand that all the interaction between views are done through controllers, so if I need to declare a function which would bind a 'click Event' to each of these colors within the HTML, should all such functions be declared within its controller?

**Question 4:**
With regards to list item HTML representation, where would the list item be declared if it needs to be dynamically generated?

My apologies for bombarding you with these questions, I have been through the documentation and endless threads, but such information is hardly discussed anywhere. Everyone wants to demo their chops, but they hardly scratch the surface. Even the official documentation lacks such details. Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to start with: http://trek.github.com/, it will answer to most of your questions. 
In your example, if you want to connect an outlet in the application view, then the {{outlet]] should be in the application template.

When calling `applicationController.connectOutlet('home')`, Ember.js will:

- search an {{outlet}} in the view's template related to the application (here the `application` template)
- search a controller named HomeController, create a view named HomeView and connect them.

See the example below, where I add the content in the HomeController in the connectOutlet method:

http://jsfiddle.net/sqJEh/19/

**UPDATE** Answering questions:

- **1**: By default you don't need to wrap an array in a Ember.A() function because Ember.js do it for you by extending the array prototype. So `[]` is already an Ember Array.
- **2**: Yeah, the {{#each}} helper provides a kind of forEach loop http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each. The controller is an ArrayController (basically proxies an array). In this example, the controller is the `homeController` instance, populated by the colors during connectOutlet. So when doing `{{#each color in controller}}`, I'm just looping over the colors array through the controller.
- **3**: It's a little harder to answer here, because I think there are several ways to deal with user interactions. It depends on what you want to do.

  - If it only deals with view concerns (for example css or dom manipulation through jquery, then I would create a child view for each color (using the itemViewClass of the {{#each}} helper) and define a `onClick` event handler.
  - If you have to interact with data, then you can use the {{action}} helper. In a router based app, the action's target will be an handler defined in the current state of the router. Here you can lookup for others controllers/models and do what you want.
  - If you want to mix both, then define the `onClick` handler in the view, and redirect the action to the router using router.send('yourAction')
- **4**: I don't understand what you mean by `dynamically generated`, so unfortunately I can't give hint here :(.

Comment: Thank you Sly for your all help. For the past couple of months, I have been going through your threads here on SOF which have been very helpful. I have gone through your fiddle, and have couple of questions which I have listed above towards the end of my question.